# Magento - how to rewrite an extension model, which has rewritten a core model?

Tags: magento, model, overriding

I'm writing an extension, which needs to overwrite the **Mage_Core_Model_Order**-Class. I know how that works. The problem now is, that there´s another Extension **(Webshopapps_Dropship)**, which also *overrides/extends* this class. Now, if I try to override the class from the *Dropship-Extension*, it won´t work.
This is what I inserted in my **config.xml**

```
<global>
    <models>
        <dropship>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order>My_Module_Model_Sales_Order</sales_order>
            </rewrite>
        </dropship>
    </models>
</global>
```

I also try to depend my module from the Dropship-extension. But this also doesn't work.

Why does it not work?

Every time I create the class via

```
$myOrderClass = Mage::getModel("sales/order");
```

I will get the Dropship-Class and not the one from my own extension.

Comment: check this http://www.webshopapps.com/blog/2010/11/resolving-magento-extension-conflicts/

Comment: i tried this already and it doesnt work :( cache is disabled. this was also my first thought. maybe there´s another problem left?

Comment: why you are not extending that class rather than overriding

Comment: how do you mean it? i need to catch Mage::getModel("sales/order"); After this, i need to have an instance of my class.